# Find the minimum value of the Hermitian polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $b\in\mathbb{C}$, and $c>0$. Find the minimum of the Hermitian polynomial $R$:

$R(t,\bar t)=a+bt+\bar b \bar t+c|t|^2$.

The only progress I have made is rewriting the function as : $(a+c|t|^2)+ 2Re(bt)$. My problem is that, from what I remember about complex differentiation, is that $f(z)=|z|^2$ is only differentiable at the origin and $g(z)=Re(z)$ is not differentiable.

There must be a way to work with the the differential equation involving $R$.

Comment: Do you want $\cdots+\overline b\overline t+\cdots$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Try writing it as $c|t-w|^2+d$ for suitable complex $w$ and real $d$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: I am getting $a+(c-2)|b|^2$